# Typo3 4.7.0 update deprecated functions?

Tags: typo3

I've just updated to Typo3 4.7.0 and most of my projects gets a call to undefined error in t3lib_div::view_array? What happens to the function view_array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [Deprecated since TYPO3 4.5](http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/46/html/classt3lib__div.html#a99605627a32fc19fceddcc91072868b7) - Use [t3lib_utility_Debug::viewArray](http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/current/html/classt3lib__utility___debug.html#a8d7d403910e0e0a4a8a3660e100f5551) instead

As you can also see it's removed from 4.7 (that's normal in TYPO3 that methods are removed in two versions after they were marked as deprecated)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know about the class.t3lib_htmlmail.php? It's deprecated?? What is the replacement?

Comment: At the main page of APIs you can search versions since 4.5 to 4.7 to determine when it was deprecated and what does it suggest instead: http://api.typo3.org/ Also check release notes about important changes: http://typo3.org/download/release-notes/typo3-4-5-release-notes/ (Unified Mail API)

Comment: class.t3lib_htmlmail.php has also gone in 4.7.0 (deprecated since 4.5). It has been replace by a new API based on SwiftMailer http://seethroughweb.com/blog/?p=366